# Question on C++ Timers

Tags: c++, networking, timer, sockets

I am currently working on a project that will act like a Online selling website such as Amazon, or Ebay in a very small scale. I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction on how to use Timers for C++. Learning Socket Programming at the moment, and was trying to incorporate the timer for the auction time when someone is selling their product.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best model. What happens when the power goes off in the middle of an auction? What happens when you need to kill your daemon for maintenance in the middle of an auction? There are probably many more circumstances like this. You'd probably be better served to just write the ending time to a database and every minute, fire a script with Cron (or something similar) to process the auctions that have ended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like [timer_create](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timer_create.2.html)?

How are you handling your sockets?  Threads or `select`?  If the latter (or something like select), timer_create will be a natural fit.

Comment: Yes I am using Select, Thank so much ^^

Answer (score 3):

C++ does not have built-in timers. What libraries you are willing to use really makes the difference in your answer.

Operating systems will have built-in timers, other libraries like Boost (mentioned in another answer), or toolkits like Qt or runtime systems like .NET will also have timers available.

I recommend you describe your environment in more detail before moving on.

What are you using for the Sockets? If it's a relatively well-known API, it will likely have a timer implementation as well. side note: You'll also want to look into threads to use for your sockets.

Comment: C++ may not have timers, but POSIX does (see my answer).

Comment: @John Zwinck Yup, that was my point. He didn't describe what he was using to code. You guessed correctly. Navigator did not.

Answer (score 1):

boost::asio timers, or the boost timer library (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/timer/index.html). Or just use the native OS timer functionalities, e.g., in Windows it'll be SetTimer and KillTime.